# Unable to parse Json array using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have this json array:

```
 [
{
"id":18,
"city":"הרצליה",
"street":"החושלים 1",
"zipcode":121209,
"state":"IL",
"lat":32.158138,
"lng":34.807838
},
{
"id":19,
"city":"הרצליה",
"street":"אבא אבן 1",
"zipcode":76812,
"state":"IL",
"lat":32.161041,
"lng":34.810410
}
]
```

And i have this class to hold the data:

```
public class MapData {
    private int id;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String state;
    private int zipcode;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    public MapData(int id, String city, String street, String state,
            int zipcode, double lat, double lng) {          
        this.id = id;
        this.city = city;
        this.street = street;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public int getZipcode() {
        return zipcode;
    }
    public void setZipcode(int zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }
    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }
    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }
    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

}
```

I'm trying to convert the json into a List of MapData objects:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<MapData>>(){}.getType();
return gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

But i get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.deliveries.models.MapData
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Type erasure. Gson knows that he has to deserialize java.util.List, but has no idea, what objects should he put into it, so he uses internal types.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech - but i told it that its a List<MapData> and according to Gson docs that is the way to do it?!

Comment: Does your method return `MapData` or `List<MapData>`?  I suspect you may be returning the wrong type.

Comment: @KevinBowersox - You have a point there, it is actually a generic method (simplified for this example), and i pass in a single object type, not a list type

Comment: @ftom2 See the answer I just posted.  It contains a GIST with a working example.  I did strip out the different charset, but I don't think that would cause an issue.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I suspect that the method calling `fromJson` is returning the wrong type.  It should return a `List<MapData>` instead of `MapData`.

Something like:

```
public static List<MapData> getData(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = "[{\"id\":18,\"city\":\"test\",\"street\":\"test 1\",\"zipcode\":121209,\"state\":\"IL\",\"lat\":32.158138,\"lng\":34.807838},{\"id\":19,\"city\":\"test\",\"street\":\"1\",\"zipcode\":76812,\"state\":\"IL\",\"lat\":32.161041,\"lng\":34.810410}]";
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<MapData>>(){}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);     
}
```

I have a fully working example of your issue in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/kmb385/5998632)

Comment: After searching for 2 days, finally got the correct approach to solve. Thanks a lot Kevin!

Answer (score -1):

```
string Json="some Json String";
JavaScriptSerializer Js = new  JavaScriptSerializer();
MapData ObjMapDat = new MapData ();
ObjMapDat =Js.Deserialize<MapData>(Json);
```