# How to Parse Json generic array with inheritance items

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

my question is not same is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712495/gson-parse-generic-json-array).
if i want to explain lets assume we have these classes (A, B, C).

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class A {
    private Integer x;
    private String type;

    public A(String type, Integer x) {
        this.type = type;
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
class B extends A {
    private Integer y;

    public B(Integer x, Integer y) {
        super("B", x);
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
class C extends A {
    private Integer z;

    public C(Integer x, Integer z) {
        super("C", x);
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

know i want to parse an array which their base classes is A. and with property named type i want to convert each item to its specific class.
something like this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
        A a = new A("A", 0);
        list.add(a);
        B b = new B(1, 2);
        list.add(b);
        C c = new C(3, 4);
        list.add(c);
        String serializedJson = gson.toJson(list);
        List<? extends A> deserializedList = gson.fromJson(serializedJson, new TypeToken<List<? extends A>>() {
        }.getType());
        for (A item : deserializedList) {
            System.out.println(item.getType());
            if (item instanceof B) {
                System.out.println(((B) item).getY());

            } else if (item instanceof C) {
                System.out.println(((C) item).getZ());

            }
        }
    }
```

serialized json is something like this

```
[{"x":0,"type":"A"},{"y":2,"x":1,"type":"B"},{"z":4,"x":3,"type":"C"}]
```

in real world, i have something like this json and want to parse it.
but when i run the code y and z properties not printed and objects are not instance of B or C.
how to achieve to this goal to parse and create each item with type property.

Comment: Isn't that because you have defined `list` as `List<A>` - instead of something like `List<? extends A>`?

Comment: I'd also say because you've tried tagging the class with a type property, you should have been able to use A["type"] or something like that as well as the instanceof stuff - maybe even A.type - not sure how Gson works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution via Gson TypeAdapterFactory mechanism.
creating a class to implement com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory. for more detail see this [link](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(A item : deserializedList) {
  switch(item.getType()) {
    case "B":
      System.out.println(((B) item).getY());
    break;
    case "C":
      System.out.println(((C) item).getZ());
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: not working. java.lang.ClassCastException ! when our objects are not instance of B or C absolutely this exception occurs!