# Using GSON to parse json object vs json array

Tags: java, android, gson

I have a JSON that is either a single object or an array of the same object.  Is there a way to parse this data using Gson where it'll distinguish between the single object vs the array?

The only solution I currently have for this is to manually parse the json and surround that with a try catch.  First I'll try parsing it as a single object, if it fails, it'll throw an exception and then I'll try to parse it as an array.

I don't want to parse it manually though...that would take me forever.
Here's an idea of what's happening.

```
public class ObjectA implements Serializable{

    public String variable;
    public ObjectB[] objectb; //or ObjectB objectb;

    public ObjectA (){}
}
```

Here's the object that can either be an array or a single object.

```
public class ObjectB implements Serializable{

    public String variable1;
    public String variable2;

    public ObjectB (){}
}
```

And then when interacting with the json response. I'm doing this.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ObjectA[] objectList = gson.fromJson(response, ObjectA[].class);
```

When the array of ObjectA's are being serialized, the json contains either an array or single object for ObjectB.

```
[
    {
        "variable": "blah blah",
        "objectb": {
            "variable1": "1",
            "variable2": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "variable": "blah blah",
        "objectb": {
            "variable1": "1",
            "variable2": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "variable": "blah blah",
        "objectb": [
            {
                "variable1": "1",
                "variable2": "2"
            },
            {
                "variable1": "1",
                "variable2": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This is the correct way:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17650863/3329488

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just changed `ObjectB[]` to `List<ObjectB>` into `ObjectA` declaration.

```
ArrayList<ObjectA> la = new ArrayList<ObjectA>();
List<ObjectA> list = new Gson().fromJson(json, la.getClass());

for (Object a : list)
{
   System.out.println(a);
}
```

and this is my result:

```
{variable=blah blah, objectb={variable1=1, variable2=2}}
{variable=blah blah, objectb={variable1=1, variable2=2}}
{variable=blah blah, objectb=[{variable1=1, variable2=2}, {variable1=1, variable2=2}]}
```

I think that in full generics era, if you do not have particular needs, you can switch from arrays to lists, you have many benefits that Gson also can use to do a flexible parsing.

Comment: This was the answer, but now I'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException because I think sometimes it's trying to parse it, but it's empty?  I'll look into it more. But thanks!

Comment: Feel free to add another question on SO with full stacktrace and code. I will surely take a look at it.

Comment: How would you handle this if "variable1","variable2" fields were dynamic? Meaning, your ObjectB class could have n number of fields. Like this json structure: http://pastebin.com/uUDCKbLV

Comment: Sorry for the redundant post. I figured it out for handling dynamic number of variables (for my question ^^). Instead of using ObjectB class, I just used the list of Map inside of ObjectA class. Something like this. 
`public List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> objectb = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();`

`ObjectA x = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ObjectA.class); `

Thanks for the idea. :)

Answer (score 5):

Try to use com.google.gson.JsonParser.

```
        String jsonString = "object json representation";
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(jsonString);

        if (jsonElement.isJsonArray()) {
            // some logic
        }
```

There are different ways to get your object using the JsonElement instance, for example - simply using the com.google.gson.Gson methods :

```
public <T>  T fromJson(com.google.gson.JsonElement json, java.lang.Class<T> classOfT) throws com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException 

public <T>  T fromJson(com.google.gson.JsonElement json, java.lang.reflect.Type typeOfT) throws com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException
```

So, study the JsonElement, JsonArray, JsonPrimitive, JsonNull and JsonObject classes. Believe, they have an adequate interface to recover your object.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try/catch it by first trying to parse the array, then falling back to parsing the single object class?

You could also do a real simple test and look to the first non whitespace character in the string you are deseralizing, if it is a "{" it is a single object, if it is a "[" it is an array

Comment: I'm using an object that has a bunch of variables to serialize it all.  I'm trying to avoid a variable by variable parsing.

Comment: These are all the same object, why does the internal complexity of the object matter, and why aren't you using gson to seralize the object as well, that is why you are using a gson. Just look at the string you are trying to deseralize and if it is valid json the first non-whitespace character should tell you if you are parsing an array or an object.

Comment: Check out my edit, maybe that'll kind of clarify what I mean when I'm not looking at it string by string.