# JSON parsing of array that contain object and string both

Tags: android, json

I am getting gson error when I parse following json. If anybody have some idea how can i parse this json then please tell me.

```
{
    "video": [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        {
            "date": "25-sep-2014",
            "day": "monday",
            "city": "chandigarh"
        }
    ] }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: post code and logcat

Comment: Unless you post code nobody can help you. The JSON you show there is valid so the problem is obviously in your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can using gson library, it's easiest way [Using Gson to parse json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993414/using-gson-to-parse-json-object-vs-json-array)