# Creating JSONArray from JSONObjects

Tags: java, arrays, json, object

I have json libs (json-simple) and trying to make jsonarray from jsonobjects. 
My aim to make JSON string look something like string below

```
[{"name": "somename","surname": "somesurname"},
 {"name": "somename2","surname": "somesurname2"}]
```

and it will have possibility of adding new objects in the same array.

This what im "hardcoding" now.

```
    JSONObject obj= new JSONObject();
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

    for(int i = 0 ; i< arr.size() ; i++)
    {
      obj.put("name", name);
      obj.put("surname", surname);

      arr.add(obj);
      obj= new JSONObject();
    }
```

Comment: Your code seems to work, what exactly is your problem with it?

Comment: What's your question? Why do you use `i` to iterate over an empty array? Where are `name` and `surname` declared?

Comment: @still_learning name and surname are passed from the console input. why i - trying to use JSONarray like usuall array

Comment: @dhke the problem is - when im writing in json file my output is [] but. if I doesnt using construction "for" - all working fine, but every time, when adding new info creatin new array

Comment: One suggestion because you do not use Gson? Here are two examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993414/using-gson-to-parse-json-object-vs-json-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186806/gson-turn-an-array-of-data-objects-into-json-android I hope this helps.