# How to parse a JSON object containing JSON array through Gson?

Tags: android, json, gson

I am creating an Android app, where I am getting some response in the form of JSON from web.

That JSON file's structure is like this:

```
{"result": "someresult", "array": [{object1},{object2}]}
```

Currently I am using the `gson.fromJson()` method to parse this JSON, but the problem is that array is a `JSONArray` and its throwing exception that `JSONObject` is expected.
For result and array I am using `@SerializedName` annotations.
How this kind of JSON can be parsed using Gson?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Here is code:

```java
public class ResultClass {

    @SerializedName("result")
    public String result;

    @SerializedName("array")
    public JSONArray array;

    public static ResultClass getresultFromJSON(String json) {
        try {
            ResultClass resultclass = new Gson().fromJson(json, ResultClass.class);
            return resultclass ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: show your implementation, it will makes easier to get help

Comment: show your implementation, and w'll help to fix it instead of asking us to make you a new one.

Comment: Use this link for parsing your JSON. It Helps you 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Parse JSON Array in Android with Gson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371274/how-to-parse-json-array-in-android-with-gson)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON Array using GSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057695/parsing-json-array-using-gson)

Comment: i have edited my question. added code
@PhanDinhThai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi if your json looks like this

```
{"status": "success",
"data": [
  {
    "trip_id": "5",
    "ride_id": "5",
    "start_location": "8 Rd No 14, Dhaka 1209, Bangladesh",
    "end_location": "Uttara Dhaka, Dhaka Division, Bangladesh",
    "date": "2017-03-14 17:36 PM",
    "time_from": "1489491394079.5322 ",
    "time_to": "1489493194079.5322 ",
    "status": 5,
    "trip_earn": "",
    "currency": "CAD"

  },
{
        "trip_id": "5",
        "ride_id": "5",
        "start_location": "8 Rd No 14, Dhaka 1209, Bangladesh",
        "end_location": "Uttara Dhaka, Dhaka Division, Bangladesh",
        "date": "2017-03-14 17:36 PM",
        "time_from": "1489491394079.5322 ",
        "time_to": "1489493194079.5322 ",
        "status": 5,
        "trip_earn": "",
        "currency": "CAD"

      }
]
}
```

then your write a class like that for parsign the data

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public List<Datum> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```

and

```
public class Datum {

@SerializedName("trip_id")
@Expose
private String tripId;
@SerializedName("ride_id")
@Expose
private String rideId;
@SerializedName("start_location")
@Expose
private String startLocation;
@SerializedName("end_location")
@Expose
private String endLocation;
@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private String date;
@SerializedName("time_from")
@Expose
private String timeFrom;
@SerializedName("time_to")
@Expose
private String timeTo;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Integer status;
@SerializedName("trip_earn")
@Expose
private String tripEarn;
@SerializedName("currency")
@Expose
private String currency;

public String getTripId() {
return tripId;
}

public void setTripId(String tripId) {
this.tripId = tripId;
}

public String getRideId() {
return rideId;
}

public void setRideId(String rideId) {
this.rideId = rideId;
}

public String getStartLocation() {
return startLocation;
}

public void setStartLocation(String startLocation) {
this.startLocation = startLocation;
}

public String getEndLocation() {
return endLocation;
}

public void setEndLocation(String endLocation) {
this.endLocation = endLocation;
}

public String getDate() {
return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
this.date = date;
}

public String getTimeFrom() {
return timeFrom;
}

public void setTimeFrom(String timeFrom) {
this.timeFrom = timeFrom;
}

public String getTimeTo() {
return timeTo;
}

public void setTimeTo(String timeTo) {
this.timeTo = timeTo;
}

public Integer getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getTripEarn() {
return tripEarn;
}

public void setTripEarn(String tripEarn) {
this.tripEarn = tripEarn;
}

public String getCurrency() {
return currency;
}

public void setCurrency(String currency) {
this.currency = currency;
}

}
```

use like

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonInString = "{\"userId\":\"1\",\"userName\":\"chayon\"}";
Example user= gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Example.class);
user.getdata().get(position)
```

Comment: @Chayon Ahmed where should we get the position

Comment: could you explain more i am not getting your question.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Response POJO classes using [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).

Add GSON dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
}
```

Convert your `json` to specific `pojo` class as below:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Response response = gson.fromJson(response, Response.class);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just create class with structure:

```
class ResultClass {
 String result;
 ArrayData[] array;
}

class ArrayData {
  String field1;
  String field2;
}
```

After that just use fromJson method:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
ResultClass resultClass = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ResultClass.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

Typo... You're getting exception because your `Gson` instance is not instructed on how to deal with `JSONArray` (I believe, it's fully-qualified name is `org.json.JSONArray`), whilst the Gson equivalent is `com.google.gson.JsonArray`. So the following mapping won't fail:

```java
@SerializedName("array")
public JsonArray array;
```

Note that you've burned on mixing two different libraries twice, and now while describing the exception you're getting: Gson does not report a `JSONObject` or whatever like that (it merely does not have any clue on that type), but it reports the `BEGIN_OBJECT` token (an internal representation of `{`) type since JSON objects are default for unknown non-primitive types except primitives and arrays.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 33 path $.array
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 33 path $.array
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
    ... 12 more
```

Also consider **not** using `JsonArray` with your application data classes like that one you're trying to parse (see the [RSCh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1972810/rsch)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42926122/166589)). Having JSON-related stuff in those classes usually marks a code smell: some fields are "true Java", some fields are "JSON only". For example, you can define another nested object mapping class and just tell Gson it must be a JSON array in your enclosing class `ResultClass`, say something like:

```java
@SerializedName("array")
public List<YourElementClass> array;
```

or

```java
@SerializedName("array")
public YourElementClass[] array;
```

A typo can affect much.